# CentOS - error while using yum

Tags: centos, yum

I get this error when I try to use yum,

```
http://iredmail.org/yum/rpms/6/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] problem making ssl connection
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: iRedMail. Please verify its path and try again
```

I tried the below but the error persists.

```
yum clean all
rm /var/lib/rpm/__db*
rpm --rebuilddb
yum update
```

Please let me know how to fix this, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Create repo.disabled inside **/etc/yum.repos.d**

```
[root@centos ~]# mkdir /etc/yum.repos.d/repo.disabled
[root@centos ~]# ls /etc/yum.repos.d/
centos.repo centos.repo  centos-updates.repo  centos-updates-testing.repo  
repo.disabled
```

Then move all these **3** repo files into **repo.disabled** folder :

```
[root@centos ~]# mv /etc/yum.repos.d/centos.repo/etc/yum.repos.d/repo.disabled
[root@centos ~]# mv /etc/yum.repos.d/centos-updates.repo/etc/yum.repos.d/repo.disabled
[root@centos ~]# mv /etc/yum.repos.d/centos-updates-testing.repo/etc/yum.repos.d/repo.disabled
```

List out the updated files and folders inside /etc/yum.repos.d :

```
[root@centos ~]# ls -l /etc/yum.repos.d/
total 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   92 Aug 18 00:09 centos.repo
 drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Aug 18 11:27 repo.disabled
```

NOTE : Only file **centos.repo** and the folder **repo.disabled** should  exist.

Now you gotta run yum clean all to clear the cache and everything should work just fine.

```
[root@centos ~]# yum clean all
```